# Convert Option<RefCell<T>> to Option<&T>

Tags: rust

We know that it's easy to convert a value of type `RefCell<T>` to a value of type `&T` for use as a parameter in a function:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: RefCell<i32> = RefCell::new(0);
    my_func(a.borrow().deref());
}

fn my_func(i: &i32) {}
```

In my scenario, the `RefCell`s are stored in a `HashMap`, so they get obtained wrapped in an `Option`. I also want the function I pass them to have the notion of option, but I only want to pass the non-mutable reference, not the whole `RefCell`. We can achieve this like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Option<RefCell<i32>> = Some(RefCell::new(0));

    match a {
        Some(ref_cell) => my_func(Some(ref_cell.borrow().deref())),
        None => my_func(None)
    };
}

fn my_func(i: Option<&i32>) {}
```

This works, but in my specific scenario, `my_func` takes several of these `Option<&T>`s as a parameter, so doing it this way means the `match` just gets nested for each parameter and grows exponentially. It would therefore be helpful to have someway of doing this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Option<RefCell<i32>> = Some(RefCell::new(0));

    let c = match a {
        Some(ref_cell) => Some(ref_cell.borrow().deref()), // won't compile as this borrow won't live long enough
        None => None
    };

    my_func(c);
}

fn my_func(i: Option<&i32>) {}
```

So essentially I want to be able to convert from `Option<RefCell<T>>` to `Option<&T>`. I feel like this should be possible somehow but I can't figure out a way to do it. I always run into some issue of performing the `.borrow()` on the `RefCell` but it not living long enough.

Comment: In addition to the answer, note that `match` can be used in expression position, like `my_func(match a { Some(ref_cell) => Some(ref_cell.borrow().deref()), None => None })`. The `Option::map()` method makes more sense here, but `match` in this position can be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the methods on `Option`:

```
a.as_ref().map(RefCell::borrow).as_deref()
```

- [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) is used to convert the `Option<RefCell<_>>` into a `Option<&RefCell<_>>` to avoid consuming it. If you already have a `Option<&RefCell<_>>` because you got it from `hash_map.get()` or similar, then you can skip this.
- [`map(RefCell::borrow)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) is used to call `.borrow()` on the value if it exists. This will create a `Option<Ref<'_, _>>`.
- [`as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) is the equivalent of calling `.deref()` on the value if it exists.

---

It is important to do it this way instead of trying to merge the `.borrow()` and `.deref()` in a single `.map()` call because this keeps the intermediate `Ref<'_, _>` value alive.

```
a.as_ref().map(|a| a.borrow().deref())
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
 --> src/main.rs:8:24
  |
8 |     a.as_ref().map(|a| a.borrow().deref())
  |                        ----------^^^^^^^^
  |                        |
  |                        returns a reference to data owned by the current function
  |                        temporary value created here
```

Also, if have multiple parameters like this and you want to split them out into variables, be sure to take the `Ref<'_, _>` part *on its own* and use `.as_deref()` where you use it. Again this is needed to keep the intermediate `Ref<'_, _>` alive:

```
let a_ref = a.as_ref().map(RefCell::borrow);
let b_ref = b.as_ref().map(RefCell::borrow);
let c_ref = c.as_ref().map(RefCell::borrow);

f(a_ref.as_deref(), b_ref.as_deref(), c_ref.as_deref());
```